# php require not working after load() method to refresh a div

Tags: php, jquery, path

I have inside my div a php require to

```
require('inc/coreturni/list.php');
```

that requires again a db connection

```
require('inc/connect.inc.php');
```

and they both work when I load the page.

but if I try to refresh the div, by refreshing the first include file after a click event, with jquery load()

I got the following path error:

> Warning: require(inc/connect.inc.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory     in C:\xampp\htdocs\taximat\inc\coreturni\list.inc.php on line 2
>
> Fatal error: require(): Failed opening required 'inc/connect.inc.php' (include_path='.;C:\xampp\php\PEAR') in C:\xampp\htdocs\taximat\inc\coreturni\list.inc.php on line 2

why the path should be different? how could i fix it?

Comment: Use an absolute path instead of a relative one

Comment: I don't like to use absolute paths and I would like to understand and learn why it doesn't work

Comment: Why do you say absolute? His code won't be portable at all if he does that. Just a little confused by your response.

Comment: An absolute path can be defined dynamically

Comment: @Gabz You don't have to like them to use them. Obviously your path is wrong and the best way to define where it is, is to use a full path.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your error explains it all:

> Warning: require(**inc/connect.inc.php**): failed to open stream: No such
>   file or directory in
>   **C:\xampp\htdocs\taximat\inc\coreturni\list.inc.php** on line 2
>
> Fatal error: require(): Failed opening required '**inc/connect.inc.php**'
>   (include_path='.;C:\xampp\php\PEAR') in
>   **C:\xampp\htdocs\taximat\inc\coreturni\list.inc.php** on line 2

Notice how it says it can’t find `inc/connect.inc.php` in this directory:

```
C:\xampp\htdocs\taximat\inc\coreturni
```

It’s because your `require` statements are referring to relative paths. So when the file `list.inc.php` is loaded, the `require` is assuming that `inc/connect.inc.php` is located in `C:\xampp\htdocs\taximat\inc\coreturni`. Which is why it is failing.

You should set a base path in your app like so. Just a note that I am unclear on forward-slash or back-slash syntax in a case like this since I work mainly on Mac & Unix systems and the error shows windows paths, but the PHP is showing Unix paths.

```
$BASE_PATH='/xampp/htdocs/taximat/inc/coreturni/';
```

And the require all files like this:

```
require($BASE_PATH . 'inc/coreturni/list.php');
```

And like this:

```
require($BASE_PATH . 'inc/connect.inc.php');
```

That way no matter where the files are called from, the `require` will use an absolute path to the file. And since `$BASE_PATH` is a one-time variable you set you can just set it in your main config file and not worry about it. To make the code portable, just change `$BASE_PATH` based on system setups.

Answer (score 1):

When the page is displayed for the first time, your paths are like this:

```
page.php
inc/
    coreturni/
        list.php
    connect.php
```

In other words, all `require` statements will be relative as seen from `page.php`.

However, when you request `list.php` directly using AJAX, it looks more like this:

```
list.php
../
    connect.php
```

Now, the `require` should have been for `../connect.php`.

**Solution**

One way to solve this is by calculating the absolute path based on the file currently being processed (i.e. `list.php`) like this:

```
require dirname(__DIR__) . '/connect.php';
```

The `dirname(__DIR__)` construct will always yield the directory on your file system that's one higher up than the current script is in.